# How to create a DispatcherObject asynchronously with async/await?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Clearly, there is something I am not understandig with async/await.

What is wrong with the following code? It creates the `FDecoder` object in an async task. But after that, whenever I try to access the FDecoder field I get an InvalidOperation exception stating that the object is owned by another thread. I thought that's the cool thing about await, that i get the results back into the calling thread...?

```
//could take very long for image from web
private Task<GifBitmapDecoder> OpenFileTask(string filename, bool forceReload = false)
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
        {
            return new GifBitmapDecoder(new Uri(filename, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), forceReload ? BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache : BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
        });
}

GifBitmapDecoder FDecoder;
public async void OpenFileAsync(string filename, bool forceReload = false)
{
    FDecoder = await OpenFileTask(filename, forceReload);
    OpenCompleted(); // do stuff with FDecoder field, throws invalid thread exception
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, what i found out is that the actual GifBitmapDecoder object the Task creates is a [DispatcherObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has thread affinity. This is the main problem... It appears that the only way is to get all needed data out of the Dispatcher object in the async task and pass back a normal object without thread affinity. But if anyone knows a better method, please tell me.

Comment: UI objects must be created and manipulated on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, because (as you rightly point out) `GifBitmapDecoder` inherits from `DispatcherObject`. This means it has an implementation which does not allow just any thread to invoke its operations.

To work with any `DispatcherObject` you should make calls through its [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. The returned `Dispatcher` object lets you schedule delegates against the real object in a way that's compatible with its internal threading model via [`InvokeAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invokeasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var decoder = new GifBitmapDecoder(...);
var operation = decoder.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { }); // Do things here!
```

This pattern, rather than returning a TPL `Task` returns a [`DispatcherOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcheroperation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (presumably because it pre-dates TPL). This very task-like object lets you examine the state of the operation and get any results. It's also awaitable, meaning you can use it with `await` just like a TPL `Task`:

```
await decoder.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { });
```

In your specific problem, you should use this pattern in your `OpenCompleted()` method. You will probably want to make it `OnCompletedAsync()` and return a `Task` to enable you to capture the UI Synchronization Context for your continuations and let the TPL handle marshalling calls back from the `Dispatcher` to the UI thread.

```
public async void OpenFileAsync(string filename, bool forceReload = false)
{
    FDecoder = await OpenFileTask(filename, forceReload);
    await OpenCompletedAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You always end up back in the same *context*, but not all contexts are tied to a single thread. Notably, the Thread Pool context treats all thread pool threads as being equal.

But I don't think that that's the specific issue here - you're using `Task.Run()` which is meant to run code in the thread pool. So even if your `await` switches everything back into the UI context, it doesn't matter because you run some of the code, explicitly, in the thread pool.

Comment: ok, that makes sense now... but how can i solve the problem? what is the correct way to start the task async and get the return object back and access it in the calling thread?

Comment: @thalm - I'd suggest, if possible, to move *all* of the image processing off into a dedicated thread. Or if you really do want to use the `GifBitmapDecoder` on the UI thread then you'll have to take the hit and create it on that thread also.

Comment: that's very unsatisfying. after the decoder is loaded i have to copy the gif frames into DirectX textures for further use in a game like main loop and use some meta data from the decoder to configure stuff. maybe async/ await is not the right choice here?

Comment: @thalm in that case, you could use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` to share the data between the asynchronous decoding thread(s) and the UI thread.  Enqueue the bitmap data from the decoder in one thread, and dequeue it in the thread that copies it into the texture.

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Run()` schedules to the threadpool, so your `GifBitmapDecoder` is being created on a different thread.

Comment: ok, so it belongs to the other thread with executes async, but what would be the correct solution then? how can i access it correctly?

Comment: @thalm You create it in the thread that you plan to use it from, namely the UI thread.

Comment: yes ok, but does this not only turn the problem around? then the async task cannot access FDecoder to perform the loading...?

Comment: @thalm Why don't you manually download the bitmap data in your thread, then create your GifBitmapDecoder() in the dispatcher thread once it has all arrived. That way the long running bit is async, but the GUI class is created and used on the dispatch thread.

Answer (score -1):

OpenFileTask is returning a `task<GifBitMapDecoder>`. You will likely need

`Task <GifBitMapDecoder> t = OpenFileTask();`

`Fdecoder = t.result; //Returns the GifBitMapDecoder object.`

Don't know much about the async stuff though, but probably is the same as you have it.

Source:C#5.0 in a nutshell.

Comment: And when he does that, and uses the result, it'll throw an `InvalidOperationException` because that object has thread affinity.

Comment: I'm new to threading myself, but what would be the point of doing something on another thread if you can't return any values?

task.return should wait until the task is finished and return the object that was specified.

Comment: The problem is not with `Task`.  It functions fine.  The problem is that the specific object being created cannot be accessed from multiple threads.  It has thread affinity.  If he were using a different object that didn't have thread affinity then it would work just fine.  Having said *that*, It's also improper to be calling `Result` here, unless the task has already completed.  That would be synchronously blocking the UI thread.  It should *asynchronously* wait for the operation to complete, as is demonstrated in the OP's code.